# How to sort fields in PhpStorm including comments

Tags: phpstorm, jetbrains-ide, code-formatting

I have a bunch of fields, like

```php
/**
 * @var string
 * Some stuff here
 */
private $var3;


/**
 * @var int
 * Some other stuff
 */
private $var2;

// Just a comment
private $var1;
```

I'd like to have them all sorted alphabetically. The end result should be

```php
// Just a comment
private $var1;

/**
 * @var int
 * Some other stuff
 */
private $var2;

/**
 * @var string
 * Some stuff here
 */
private $var3;
```

I tried using a plugin called "String manipulation", but it doesn't keep the comments together with the fields, sorting resulting in something random like this

```
* @var int
* @var string

* Some other stuff
 * Some stuff here
 */
 */
/**

/**
 // Just a comment
 private $var1;
 private $var2;
private $var3;
```

I also tried to use the Rearrange code built-in the IDE. I kept the default rules, but changed the "fields" one to "Order by name". Doesn't seem to do anything...
[image]

I don't have any other ideas on what to try, and with many large files, doing this manually is a tedious work.

Any solutions?

Comment: Unfortunately, `order by name` doesn't work if `by modifiers` is enabled at the same time. Please vote: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-30563

Comment: Wow, that issue is 4 years old :( I up'ed it.
Is there any workaround?